# Key in Dictionary Before Extraction [Pythonic Approach]

Tags: python

What is a "pythonic" approach to checking to see if an element is in the dictionary before extracting it and using it in a comparison?

For example:

Currently, I do

```
if "key1" in list2 and list2["key1"]=="5":
  print "correct"
```

so that it will short-circuit on the first conditional if it fails. However, this leads to long conditional statements.

Is there however a more "pythonic" approach? I'm guessing that wrapping the conditional in a try catch is an even worse idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach is perfectly pythonic. Another, slightly different would be

```
if list2.get("key1", <-1,0 or any sensible default, e.g. None>) == 5:
    print "correct"
```

With this approach you employ [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method which allows for safe extraction of value from dict (and provides a way to specify default value)

Answer (score 7):

Nope - try/except is absolutely fine:

```
try:
    if list2['key1'] == '5':
        # do something
except KeyError:
    # key wasn't found
except ValueError:
    # most likely value wasn't comparable...
```

Comment: A `TypeError` won't be raised if you compare incomparable types for equality.

Comment: I think it's ugly. It is fine, it is robust, but ugly nontheless.

Comment: @JonClements It's only ordering relations that need to be the same (or explicitly comparable) types. If Python doesn't know how to compare values of two different types, it simply evaluates to False. You only need to catch the `KeyError` here for when `key1` isn't found.

Comment: @chepner indeed, I'll leave it here for a possibly more general use case of `if blah < 3 and blah > 5` etc... etc...

Answer (score 4):

```
if list2.get("key1")==5:
    print("correct")
```

I wouldn't call a dictionary "list2", though.

If the value can be None, you can choose another default:

```
if list2.get("key1", object()) in my_other_list:
    print("correct")
```

or use exceptions, or your "long" way.

Comment: Testing two incompatible types for equality should just evaluate to False, not raise an exception.

Comment: You can still compare equality of non-ints to ints.

Comment: @BrenBarn I should have said if the key isn't found, the comparison to `None` will fail (at least in Py3.x)

Comment: `None==5` is still simply False in python 3.1

Comment: @chepner omfg - *sighs* - thanks for attending my brain burps ;)

Comment: If you need to distinguish between `None` as a value and no value, I think the usual approach is to use an `object` sentinel, e.g. `dict2.get("key1", object())`.

Comment: @dsm yup - but you still need to be about to refer to `object()` so one needs to make sure it's defined outside the `.get` first

Comment: @JonClements: not if all you're doing is comparing whether it's equal to something, like 5, or testing its membership in a list.

Comment: @dsm yes - errrr, ummm.... maybe I should drink some more coffee :) [and try to pretend the last 6/7 mins doesn't actually exist *cough*]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the most pythonic way to put this would be

```
    print 'correct' if list2.get('key1') == 5
```

Comment: No. this is the most rubyic way.

Comment: Evidently I don't have much idea about ruby. Thanks @Elazar.

Comment: ruby has `do that if so` statements.